# How to create AudioBuffer(Audio) from NSdata

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, audiobuffer

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput  didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection {

    AudioBufferList audioBufferList;
    NSMutableData *data= [NSMutableData data];
    CMBlockBufferRef blockBuffer;
    CMSampleBufferGetAudioBufferListWithRetainedBlockBuffer(sampleBuffer, NULL, &audioBufferList, sizeof(audioBufferList), NULL, NULL, 0, &blockBuffer);

    for( int y=0; y< audioBufferList.mNumberBuffers; y++ ){

        AudioBuffer audioBuffer = audioBufferList.mBuffers[y];
        Float32 *frame = (Float32*)audioBuffer.mData;

        [data appendBytes:frame length:audioBuffer.mDataByteSize];

    }

    CFRelease(blockBuffer);
    CFRelease(ref);

    AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data error:nil];
    [player play];
}
```

I don't know how to convert NSdata to Audio Buffer.

AVAudioPlayer with above data returns nil with this error: Error = Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=1954115647

Answer (score 0):

Try adding player as an instance variable

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *player;
```

And then alloc your player from captureOutput:

```
self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data error:nil];
```

Hope this will work :)

Comment: thx your answer.But AVAudioPlayer still occurs error:Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=1954115647

Comment: Ok then try adding [[NSMutableData alloc]init] instead of [NSMutableData data];
eg: NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc]init]; 
and now try once

Comment: Problem still exists, is it my above method is not correct?

Comment: Can you change 
[data appendBytes:frame length:audioBuffer.mDataByteSize]; to
[data appendBytes:audioBuffer.mData length:audioBuffer.mDataByteSize];